# Google Signals/Remarketing - check if it's enabled?

Tags: google-analytics

We are trying to use Google Signals (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7532985?hl=en) for remarketing purposes but we are unsure if it is correctly enabled. We are using the following code for our implementation:

```
​​<script async
src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX"></script>

<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
dataLayer.push(arguments);
}

if (!cookieManager.googleRemarketing) {
gtag('set', 'allow_google_signals', false);
}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'XXX', {
'anonymize_ip': true,
'optimize_id': 'XXX'
});
</script>
```

We are not using any additional google ads/remarketing code, but we have enabled "Tracking-Information" => "Data collection" => "Data collection for Google Signals" (the translations might vary, because we don't use analytics in English) in Google Analytics.

It seems like there is no cookie with the name "IDE" set, like it was before when we used the normal Google Remarketing Code. Did that cookie got removed/replaced in google signals?
If so, how can we check if google signals is working correctly?

The Tag Assistant Plugin for Chrome just shows the following:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet you have:

```
gtag('set', 'allow_google_signals', false );
```

so it disable all advertising features.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/display-features

For this reason you can't see any IDE cookie.

Comment: This line will only be executed if someone denies this cookie from the cookie banner. For testing we obviously didn't execute this line. It was not executed.